# Error while trying to execute junit tests

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I'm trying to run some junit tests but I'm constantly having errors.

My `pom.xml` has the following maven dependencies:

```
<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
<junit.jupiter.version>5.0.1</junit.jupiter.version>
<junit.vintage.version>${junit.version}.1</junit.vintage.version>
<junit.platform.version>1.0.1</junit.platform.version>

<!-- junit dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
        <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I actually have three methods with `@BeforeAll`, `@Before` and `@Test` annotations. Those methods only have print functions in order to pass the tests.

The errors I'm having are the following:

```
nov 06, 2017 10:36:17 AM org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver resolveMethod
    ADVERTENCIA: Method 'public void getTest() throws java.lang.Exception' could not be resolved.
    10:36:18.048 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.tests]
    10:36:18.052 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
    10:36:18.058 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
    10:36:18.064 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.tests] from class [org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper]
    10:36:18.086 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader - Delegating to AnnotationConfigContextLoader to process context configuration [ContextConfigurationAttributes@68567e20 declaringClass = 'com.tests', classes = '{class com.tests.TestConfig}', locations = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoader'].
    10:36:18.101 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.tests]
    10:36:18.102 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.tests]: using defaults.
    10:36:18.105 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
    10:36:18.117 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
    10:36:18.117 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@27ff5d15, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4e096385, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@649bec2e, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@693fe6c9, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@34f5090e]
    10:36:18.121 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.tests]
    10:36:18.121 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.tests]
    10:36:18.151 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.tests]
    10:36:18.151 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.tests]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/LauncherDiscoveryRequest;)V
        at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:59)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.5.

I googled about it but I did not found any good response, any idea?

Comment: Could you provide sample project on GitHub so it's easier to figure out what's the problem?

Comment: I created this [repository](https://github.com/MohaSaid/testJunit) in order to replicate the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have downloaded the project from a link you provided. When I change the `add` method to be `public` everything works ok for me:

```
@Test
public void add() {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    assertEquals(2, calculator.add(1, 1), "1 + 1 should equal 2");
}
```

I tried to run tests both from IDE and maven. To run tests from maven you could try to execute the following in command line:

```
mvn clean install
```

This will both build your project and run tests for you.

My setup is:

- **Java** version: "1.8.0_131"
- **Maven** version: 3.3.9
- **IntelliJ idea** version (may be useful if you want to run tests from IDE): 2017.2.5

Comment: Looks like upgrading my IntelliJ idea version to 2017.2.5 fixes the problem. Thank you!